# Summing and Outputting Totals in Mongo View

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my mongDB backend, I have a view that, after multiple aggregation stages, outputs info that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 25k3ejfjyi32132f9z3,
    "customer_id" : 15cgrd582950jj493g5,
    "openBalance": 24,
    // other data...
},
{ 
    "_id" : 35g6ejfjfj32132f8s4, 
    "customer_id" : 23gtrd684563jj494f4
    "openBalance": 20,
    // other data...
}
```

What I need to do, as a last step, is total up all of the "openBalance" amounts for all records, and output that number in a new field along with the other data. So, in other words, based on the above data, I want to return `44` in the a field titled `totalOpenBalance`.

Is there a way I can handle this aggregation logic in a mongo view? I'm not sure how to do this, because I'm not wanting to add a field to each record returned, but instead return a value based on the total of the records? It would look something like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 25k3ejfjyi32132f9z3,
    "customer_id" : 15cgrd582950jj493g5,
    "openBalance": 24,
    // other data...
},
{ 
    "_id" : 35g6ejfjfj32132f8s4, 
    "customer_id" : 23gtrd684563jj494f4
    "openBalance": 20,
    // other data...
},
"totalOpenBalance": 44
```

Comment: I face similar issues with my mongo aggregation queries. AFAIK, there is no way to do this using the aggregation pipeline. You instead have to do this in the callback for the aggregation pipeline. You basically have to manually compute that "field" and add it to the response object. [You may be able to utilize the `$facet` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

Comment: I will check into that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the following code to the end of your pipeline

```
$group: {
    _id: null, // do not really group but throw all documents into the same bucket
    documents: { $push: "$$ROOT" }, // push each encountered document into the group
    totalOpenBalance: { $sum: "$openBalance" } // sum up all "openBalance" values
}
```

you will get something that you might be able to use:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "documents" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 25k3ejfjyi32132f9z3,
            "customer_id" : 15cgrd582950jj493g5,
            "openBalance" : 24
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 35g6ejfjfj32132f8s4,
            "customer_id" : 23gtrd684563jj494f4,
            "openBalance" : 20
        }
    ],
    "totalOpenBalance" : 44
}
```

If you want to go completely crazy which I would not really recommend then read on. By adding the following stages

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null, // do not really group but throw all documents into the same bucket
        documents: { $push: "$$ROOT" }, // push each encountered document into the group
        totalOpenBalance: { $sum: "$openBalance" } // sum up all "openBalance" values
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 0, // remove the "_id" field
        "documents": { $concatArrays: [ "$documents", [ { "totalOpenBalance": "$totalOpenBalance" } ] ] } // append a magic subdocument to the the existing documents
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$documents" // just so we can flatten the resulting array into separate documents
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$documents" // and move the content of our documents field to the root
    }
}
```

you get exactly what you asked for:

```
{
    "_id" : 25k3ejfjyi32132f9z3,
    "customer_id" : 15cgrd582950jj493g5,
    "openBalance" : 24
},
{
    "_id" : 35g6ejfjfj32132f8s4,
    "customer_id" : 23gtrd684563jj494f4,
    "openBalance" : 20
},
{
    "totalOpenBalance" : 44
}
```

This, however, is probably just an overkill...

Comment: This looks like the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: This solution helped me too! Can't tell you how long I searched for this, with no avail.